# How can I group_by and summarize using a list of column names?

Tags: r

Basically, I want to loop through, group the data by the columns in "list.group", and then create summary statistics for every column in "list.avg", "list.max", and "list.min" so that the columns are mpg_avg, wt_avg, hp_avg, mpg_max, hp_max... mpg_min, hp_min, etc.

```
data("mtcars")
    list.avg <- list("mpg","wt","hp")
    list.max <- list("mpg","hp","wt","qsec")
    list.min <- list("mpg","hp","wt","qsec")
    list.group <- list("cyl","vs","am","gear","carb")
```

So I should have a separate table for each column in list.group.

Comment: is the `list.group` same in all the cases as the lengths are different for each of the `list`

Comment: each list can be a different length

Comment: I meant the `list.group`  is it common to all the cases or not

Comment: Ohh, yes it is.

Answer (score 3):

First, it's helpful to have all the avg/max/min variables in a single list.

```
to_summarise <- 
  list(mean = c("mpg","wt","hp"),
       max = c("mpg","hp","wt","qsec"),
       min = c("mpg","hp","wt","qsec"))
```

Now we can `map` over `list.group`, and within each `list.group` value, `imap` over `to_summarise` and then `merge` all the results together.

```
library(tidyverse)

map(list.group, ~{
  grouped <- 
    mtcars %>% 
      group_by_at(.x) 
  out <- 
    imap(to_summarise, ~{
            grouped %>% 
              summarise_at(.x, setNames(list(get(.y)), .y))
    })
  out %>% 
    reduce(merge, by = .x)
})
```

Output

```
#     [[1]]
#   cyl mpg_mean  wt_mean   hp_mean mpg_max hp_max wt_max qsec_max mpg_min hp_min wt_min
# 1   4 26.66364 2.285727  82.63636    33.9    113  3.190    22.90    21.4     52  1.513
# 2   6 19.74286 3.117143 122.28571    21.4    175  3.460    20.22    17.8    105  2.620
# 3   8 15.10000 3.999214 209.21429    19.2    335  5.424    18.00    10.4    150  3.170
#   qsec_min
# 1     16.7
# 2     15.5
# 3     14.5
# 
# [[2]]
#   vs mpg_mean  wt_mean   hp_mean mpg_max hp_max wt_max qsec_max mpg_min hp_min wt_min
# 1  0 16.61667 3.688556 189.72222    26.0    335  5.424     18.0    10.4     91  2.140
# 2  1 24.55714 2.611286  91.35714    33.9    123  3.460     22.9    17.8     52  1.513
#   qsec_min
# 1     14.5
# 2     16.9
# 
# [[3]]
#   am mpg_mean  wt_mean  hp_mean mpg_max hp_max wt_max qsec_max mpg_min hp_min wt_min
# 1  0 17.14737 3.768895 160.2632    24.4    245  5.424     22.9    10.4     62  2.465
# 2  1 24.39231 2.411000 126.8462    33.9    335  3.570     19.9    15.0     52  1.513
#   qsec_min
# 1    15.41
# 2    14.50
# 
# [[4]]
#   gear mpg_mean  wt_mean  hp_mean mpg_max hp_max wt_max qsec_max mpg_min hp_min wt_min
# 1    3 16.10667 3.892600 176.1333    21.5    245  5.424    20.22    10.4     97  2.465
# 2    4 24.53333 2.616667  89.5000    33.9    123  3.440    22.90    17.8     52  1.615
# 3    5 21.38000 2.632600 195.6000    30.4    335  3.570    16.90    15.0     91  1.513
#   qsec_min
# 1    15.41
# 2    16.46
# 3    14.50
# 
# [[5]]
#   carb mpg_mean wt_mean hp_mean mpg_max hp_max wt_max qsec_max mpg_min hp_min wt_min
# 1    1 25.34286  2.4900    86.0    33.9    110  3.460    20.22    18.1     65  1.835
# 2    2 22.40000  2.8628   117.2    30.4    175  3.845    22.90    15.2     52  1.513
# 3    3 16.30000  3.8600   180.0    17.3    180  4.070    18.00    15.2    180  3.730
# 4    4 15.79000  3.8974   187.0    21.0    264  5.424    18.90    10.4    110  2.620
# 5    6 19.70000  2.7700   175.0    19.7    175  2.770    15.50    19.7    175  2.770
# 6    8 15.00000  3.5700   335.0    15.0    335  3.570    14.60    15.0    335  3.570
#   qsec_min
# 1    18.61
# 2    16.70
# 3    17.40
# 4    14.50
# 5    15.50
# 6    14.60
```

Comment: Thanks! is ~{ just a shortcut for a function?

Comment: Yes, in purrr functions such as `map`, `~{ something(.x) }` is the same as `function(x){ something(x) }`. The purr package is included in the tidyverse package.

Comment: Thanks! Haven't gotten to the point in R where I use purr extensively.

Answer (score 3):

The 'avg' is not a function in `R`.  Instead, it can be `mean`.  So, changing the object identifier name from `list.avg` to `list.mean`, keep the `list.` objects into a `list`, then loop through the `named` `list` with `imap`, remove the prefix `list.` with `str_remove`, using `group_by_at` group by the common grouping elements, then `summarise_at` the values that we loop while applying the function we `get` from the prefix removed names on those columns

```
library(tidyverse)
list.mean <- list("mpg","wt","hp")
lst(list.mean, list.max, list.min) %>% 
   imap(~ {

   func <- str_remove(.y, '^list\\.')
    vars1 <- unlist(.x)



  mtcars %>%
     group_by_at(unlist(list.group)) %>%
      summarise_at(vars(vars1), ~ get(func)(.))


  })
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `map` to loop through `list.group`, use `group_by_at` to group at each element of `list.group` as they are strings then summarize at the required columns and finally binds all together.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(list.group, ~mtcars %>% 
          #.x will be "cyl", "vs" ... etc 
          group_by_at(.x) %>% 
          {bind_cols(summarise_at(.,unlist(list.avg), list(avg=mean)),
                     summarise_at(.,unlist(list.min), list(min=min)),
                     summarise_at(.,unlist(list.max), list(max=max))
                     )
          }
    )
```

Comment: I like this one too!

Comment: Thanks  here a simple example using one variable from `list.group` `mtcars %>% 
    group_by_at("cyl") %>% 
    {bind_cols(summarise_at(.,unlist(list.avg), list(avg=mean)),
               summarise_at(.,unlist(list.min), list(min=min)),
               summarise_at(.,unlist(list.max), list(max=max))
    )}`